# Watermark in mPDF(PHP) not working correctly

Tags: php, watermark, mpdf

I have a strange problem with my php script using mPDF. I generate PDF file from HTML and I want to set watermark on each page. So I'm trying like in the manual:

```
  if($_REQUEST['WATERMARK']==1){
        $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('draft');
        $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
        $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha= 0.4;
    }
```

but it's working wrong because it set me watermark without clarity (like I will set watermarkTextAlpha= 1, overlaps on main text). But in other script (a little different) it works good.

Comment: "*But in other script (a little different) it works good.*" What is a little different?

Comment: style.css style is the same. Other script is execute without function... This is main diffrence. But I also tried bring $mpdf as global, outside function and still not works :(

Comment: Are ou outputting the text of the PDF after you set the watermark's transparency?

Comment: Yes. I set $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('draft') ... after declarate mpdf object.

Comment: I can see that @Gugu, but that wasn't the question. Where is the rest of the code for this PDF?

Comment: $mpdf = new mPDF('','',0,'',15,15,25,15,10,10,'P');
    $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
    $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
    $mpdf->use_kwt = true;

    if($_REQUEST['WATERMARK']==1){
        $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('Wersjaa robocza');
        $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
        $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha= 0.5;
    }

    $mpdf->setHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right; font-size: 12px ">fffff</div> <hr class="line">');

    $mpdf->setHTMLFooter('<hr class="line"><span style="text-align: left; font-size: 12">dddd</span><br><br><br>');

Comment: $homepage1 = $smarty->fetch(__DIR__ . '/view/file.tpl');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($homepage1);

Comment: Please edit your post above @Gugu, don't dump code in the comments.

Comment: All code for this PDF is inside function

Comment: http://wklej.org/id/1510830/

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code .

Try this code:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use core fonts only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8, 
        // A4 paper format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE, 
        // stream to browser inline
        'destination' => $destination,
        'filename'=>  'Sales_invoice/'.$model->invoice_no.'_'.$copy_text.'.pdf',
        // your html content input
        'content' => $content,  
        // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
        // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting 

        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
         'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px},
            ',

         // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => ['title' => 'Company-Profile',

                     'showWatermarkText'=>true,
            ],

         // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [ 
            'SetHeader'=>['<div class=col-md-12 >'
                .'<div class=col-md-6  style=margin-top:-30px>'

                .'</div><div class=col-md-6  style=margin-top:-15px><p></p></div>'], 
            'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
            'SetWatermarkText'=>['Draft'],


        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working code for mPdf Watermark**

Try this

```
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',20,15,48,25,10,10); 
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;    // false is default
$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
$mpdf->SetTitle("Sanros Trading Co. - Invoice");
$mpdf->SetAuthor("Sanros Trading Co.");
$mpdf->SetWatermarkText("Sanros");
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
```