# usetemplate function in mpdf doesn't working for watermark

Tags: php, watermark, mpdf

I tried to add watermark text for everypage of external pdf file. But useTemplate function which doesn't work properly. Here my code:

```
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF(''); 
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); 
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile(Yii::app()->basePath. '/../pdf/'.$model->file);
for($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++){
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
    $size = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($tplId);

    $orientation = $size['h'] > $size['w'] ? 'P':'L';
    $mpdf->AddPage($orientation);
    $mpdf->useTemplate($tplId, null, null, $size['w'], $size['h'], flase);
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('http://www.bps.go.id','0.07');
    $mpdf->watermark_font='Arial Black';
    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;

}
$mpdf->Output();
```

Generate result of those codes still in A4 format (mpdf default format). Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26903083/4290096

Comment: i've tried with that code. But that code will apply everypage of external pdf file with format A4, portrait. I suppose to apply everypage depend on their width and height. That's why i use getTemplateSize function to get size of everypage

Answer (score 0):

i've got the answer...

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++){
 $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
 $size = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($tplId);
 $mpdf->_setPageSize(array($size['w'], $size['h']), 'P');
 $mpdf->AddPage();
 $mpdf->useTemplate($tplId); 
 $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('http://www.bps.go.id','0.07');
 $mpdf->watermark_font='Arial Black';
 $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
}
```

finally :)